# How to deploy a karaf feature from a local maven repository?

Tags: maven, karaf

I've created by first project for karaf (4.0.1). So far I've got the following:

- an application bundle built with the `maven-bundle-plugin`. There are going to be more...
- a karaf feature created with the `karaf-maven-plugin`.
- a karaf-assembly created with the same plugin

So I'm ready to deliver to the customer - but I'm stuck over the development process. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791950/how-to-work-with-frequent-local-snapshot-bundle-deployments-on-karaf) answered almost all my remaining questions save one:

After having built my project by running `maven install` I think I should be able to to get my feature running on a local karaf instance using something like the command `feature:install`.

I can install my application bundle from local maven by using `bundle:install` but then I'm down to managing dependencies myself.

Really can't figure out while `bundle:install` works against my local maven repository and `feature:install` doesn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the soloution [here](http://www.cheatography.com/funthomas424242/cheat-sheets/karaf/). I knew I'd need `feature:repo-add` - but the name of this command and the [official documentation](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/commands/feature-repo-add.html) sent me thinking in entirely the wrong direction.

This command **does not add a (maven) repository**, but adds the location of a feature in the maven repository chain (so I'm thinking the old name `addUrl` was probably easier to understand).

Anyway - using `feature:repo-add mvn:<groupId>/<artifactId>/<version>/xml/features` works.

Answer (score 0):

Before installing a feature, you have to register the features repository that provides the feature using `feature:repo-add`

using `feature:repo-add mvn:<groupId>/<artifactId>/<version>/xml`